# Use a variable in a function

Tags: python, list, function, variables

```
import random

b = random.choice([2309,1897,2307])

def function(user):
    user.getApple().eatTheApple(b, 2000, 50, 1, 8663, 4444)
```

I am fairly new to python but I'm picking it up quickly. B is the variable and it equals a 4 digit number. This 4 digit number will be picked at random.

Then I would like this value to be placed alongside other fixed values such as 2000, 50, 1, 8663 and 4444.

How could I do this? I've been looking around for ages.

Comment: what's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: You have some code, but what is relevant about the code?  Does it represent something that doesn't work?

Comment: What's a `user`? Does the input to `function` actually have a `getApple` method that returns a thing with an `eatTheApple` method?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to figure out how to use a global variable in a function?  Please help us out by giving us a little more context behind what you want to happen, and what's going wrong.

Comment: You've also specify that b is a four-digit number; do you want a check in the function to see if that's true, or do we assume that it's been appropriately calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add b as a parameter of the function, if I understand you correctly.

Consider:

```
def function(user,b):
    user.getApple().eatTheApple(b, 2000, 50, 1, 8663, 4444)
```

Then we could test with (assuming the class User is defined somewhere else):

```
import random
myUser = User()

b = random.choice([2309,1897,2307])
function( myUser , b )
```

We've made a function of two parameters, and passed them both in! An alternative would be:

```
def function(user):
    user.getApple().eatTheApple( random.choice([2309,1897,2307], 2000, 50, 1, 8663, 4444)
```

I've assumed that User is a class somewhere, so there might be a prettier way to do this yet, if this is appropriate for your circumstances (it might not be). We have our class declaration:

```
class User:
    def __init__( self ):
        #this code is executed when the class is created
        self.b = random.choice([2309,1897,2307])

    def function( self ):
        #this code is owned by each User object
        user.getApple().eatTheApple(self.b, 2000, 50, 1, 8663, 4444)
```

That would be executed by:

```
myUser = User()
myUser.function()
```

Python likes object-oriented design, so this would be nice! However, it assumes that the "b" value is personal to the user, and doesn't change. I'll give you alternatives, if it does